# Event firing in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using custom binding to attach the autonumeric library(to use only numbers in the fields). After the user leaves the field, if something changed the program is going to run a js function called: runcomputepage. The problem is that the event never fires:

If I leave by default the bind(data-bind="value" instead of data-bind="number") the event run.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.number = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'focusout', function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).val());
            $(element).autoNumeric('init');
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).val(value);
        $(element).autoNumeric('init');
    }
};
```

Comment: Please attach your code by jsfiddle

Comment: Also, you need to show us your code in use not just your binding handler...

Comment: Try using ['blur'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.blur) as the event.